# Windows 7 and 8 file overwrite and delete error for file created by another user

Tags: windows, file, windows-7, vb6

In Windows 7 and 8 with default settings and permissions, a file which is created by a user cannot be overwritten by another user. Also cannot delete the file.But this is not the case in Windows XP. So is there any option to overwrite the file. I am facing problem in my vb6 application which is installed in a PC. It can be used by any users in that pc. So if another user access the software, then software saves some file which is common to all users ,in this case it gives error for the user other than in which user that file created. So please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this can also occur all the way back to NT 3.1 depending on where the file is created.  Some special folders have security settings that result in "owner/publisher" style security on created objects (files and folders), which is exactly what you are describing.

A lot of people who slowly dragged their feet into the NT world from Win9x had XP as their first experience.  They rely on appcompat and logging on as an admin or power user in the attempt to pretend they are still on insecure 9x systems.

Welcome to 1993.

The way applications are meant to deal with this is *during elevated installation* you create a folder for such data under one of the shared special folders and set the desired security on it, in your case perhaps Full Control for Everyone (which is nowadays logged-on users, i.e. excluding Guest).